# Is it possible to duplicate and rename an application?

Tags: applications, bash, unix

I tried to do this:

```
➜/Applications$ cp -R Atom.app OtherAtom.app
```

but opening OtherAtom just basically opens Atom. It does not produce another application in the command tab menu.

Maybe I need to change the name inside of the application Contents?

The requirements of my project do not necessitate that there actually be a clone of the app, but I do require the ability to run multiple instances of the app and to be able to rename each instance in the command tab menu.

Thank you for checking out my question!

Comment: What happens if you just duplicate it in Finder (select the app, then Cmd-D)? I'd expect that to work in the general case, though it's certainly possible Atom is doing something that will prevent multiple instances from running.

Comment: (And even if it works, all instances will be writing to the same Preferences and Application Support files, which may cause weird problems.)

Comment: @calum_b Some apps will work with a different name.  Depends on how the app was written.  Some apps make the top most folder be the app name.

Comment: @historystamp @calum_b Using cmd-d behaves in the same way the `cp` in a shell did. Maybe I need to change the name of OtherAtom in its package Contents and Preferences and Applications Support?

Comment: try it and see.  Do you have a link to this app?

Comment: see this thread; https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/60550/multiple-installs-of-the-same-application?rq=1

Comment: The problem may be that they are both using the same Application Support folder/files (where all of the information is likely stored). I don't know if there is a way to run multiple instances (without using a vm) of the app, it depends if it lets you chose where the stored files are (unlikely). Also, changing the name inside Contents could break the whole app.

Comment: It would be helpful if we had a copy of the app to experiment with though

Comment: @Sam https://atom.io/ Maybe I can run it with docker to solve the problem